# Plesk 410 Directory

Tags: nginx, plesk, 410-gone

Plesk allows adding "Additional nginx directives" for hosted websites.

[image: Plesk - Additional nginx directives]

I'm trying to use this to set a 410 header on some old directories, but I can't find anything as simple as `RewriteRule ^rss/ - [G]` was in `.htaccess` rules. I've seen `location /rss/ { return 410; }` [suggested](https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?11,256936,256939) but that doesn't work.

Is there a simple nginx directive to 410 a whole directory in Plesk?

Comment: Have you seen this related question on ServerFault? [return error 410 for location regex? in nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/646154/return-error-410-for-location-regex-in-nginx)

Comment: No joy there either; that's more query-specific.

Comment: One thing I would try would be taking off the trailing slash:   `location /rss { return 410; }`    I have a hunch that will do it based on the examples I've seen.

Comment: I tried that too, but still no luck.

Comment: Another to try is `location ^~ /rss {return 410; }`   Regex matches all get applied first, so this makes the rule get applied earlier in case it is other rules getting in the way.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with nginx.   I'd never used it before today, but I just installed it to test this out.   If I add any of the above rules into */etc/nginx/sites-available/default* and restart the server I see the appropriate status code when I visit a URL like `/rss/feed.rss`.    I think that somehow Plesk isn't putting the rules in, or isn't putting them in where they can be effective.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller `location ^~ /rss {return 410;}` did it! Ping that on as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
location ^~ /rss {
    return 410;
}
```

Regex matches all get applied earlier than other rules, so this makes the rule get applied first.  The problem may be that there is some other rule that is getting applied first.